# How does a fancy pointer look like?

Tags: c++, pointers

The C++ reference mentions a concept called [fancy pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Fancy_pointers). I learned about their existence from a recent heavily downvoted and afterwards deleted question.

The definition is rather vague:

> When the member type pointer is not a raw pointer type, it is commonly referred to as a "fancy pointer".

Their use case example is:

> An example of a fancy pointer is the mapping address-independent
> pointer boost::interprocess::offset_ptr, which makes it possible to
> allocate node-based data structures such as std::set in shared memory
> and memory mapped files mapped in different addresses in every
> process. Fancy pointers can be used independently of the allocator
> that provided them, through the class template std::pointer_traits.

I don't understand that explanation. What is the syntax for creating a fancy pointer and why can't I use a regular pointer in this case?

Comment: When community editing goes wrong...

Comment: My take is anything that acts like a pointer, but is not.  Like pretty much all iterators are custom class types, but they behave just like a pointer (sometimes there are restrictions and you cannot do all the operations supported by a pointer).  An abstraction that acts like a pointer is a *fancy pointer*.

Comment: That other question was, at the heart of it, *unclear* as to what was being asked about (no reference to where the term was seen or what context it was from). Also, I would not consider "fancy pointer" a common term.

Comment: @crashmstr well, if it is in the C++ reference, that seems common enough.

Comment: The edit which introduced this nonsensical "term" is given [here](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Fconcept%2FAllocator&diff=89066&oldid=86365). I don't know if said user was acting in jest, or seriously, but enough of this foolishness.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was just in the process of improving the related question. But my problem was that I am not fully sure how to interpret the term.

Comment: @Beginner I've been working with C++ for over 25 years and this was the first time I've heard the term.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok. I get it, the term in the cpp reference is silly, too...

Comment: Good on you :-)

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, I get it, I never thought the cpp-reference would contain nonsensical edits.

Comment: imho you should not delete the question. If the term does not exist and is just coming from a misunderstanding, then this is an answer

Comment: @NathanOliver can you post this as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: I found a "blog post" initially from 2014 that makes reference to "fancy pointers" [A visitor’s guide to C++ allocators](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_user_guide.html).

Comment: @Beginner I didn't post an answer as it was just a guess on my part.  I have never heard of a fancy pointer before today and I've been working with C++ for about 10 years.

Comment: @NathanOliver but I think your answer is correct and it also matches with the definition in that blog post.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, my comment was nonsense. Please forget about it, I deleted it already.

Comment: Some technical discussion about it with examples: https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A fancy pointer is just a term for something that acts like a pointer but is not.  Take, for example, an iterator.  Pretty much all iterators are custom class types, but they behave just like a pointer (sometimes there are restrictions and you cannot do all the operations supported by a pointer as they do not provide random access but that is part of the fanciness.)

To put it another way: An abstraction that acts like a pointer is a *fancy pointer*.